# Listbox last element incorrect rendering

Tags: wpf

I got trouble with the listbox. Please, check the screenshot down there. The last element is kind of "eaten" by the listbox external border (I defined appropriate MaxHeight). Can someone help me?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="QCTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Expander x:Name="expander" Header="{Binding}">
            <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBox Name="ComponentNameTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource BorderlessTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding ComponentName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="1">Количество цитат:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="ComponentVolumeTextBlock" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Text="{Binding Volume}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Expander.HeaderTemplate>

            <!-- Контекстное меню экспандера -->
            <Expander.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Оригинал 'My Clippings.txt'">
                        <MenuItem Header="Удалить из оригинала..." 
                                  Command="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteFromMyClippingsCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </MenuItem>
                 </ContextMenu>
            </Expander.ContextMenu>

            <!-- Внутреннее содержание экспандера -->
            <Grid Name="ExpanderContentContainer" 
                  Height="{Binding ElementName=ComponentChildsListBox, Path=ActualHeight}">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                               Width="2" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight}"
                               Fill="Black" 
                               Margin="2"                               
                               />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                            Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                    <TextBox Name="ComponentCommentTextBox" 
                             Text="{Binding Comment, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=QCCCommentConvrtr}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             BorderThickness="0"
                             GotFocus="ComponentCommentTextBox_GotFocus"
                             Margin="1"
                             />

                    <ListBox Name="ComponentChildsListBox"
                             BorderBrush="Transparent"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ChildsCollection}"
                             ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                             MaxHeight="300" 
                             Margin="1"
                             Style="{StaticResource LibraryViewListBoxStyle}"
                             />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Expander>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDbe.png)

Comment: Code or properties screen needed

Comment: @Сергей without XAML cannot be sure but my bet is on that you're using something like vertical `StackPanel` which doesn't care what max height you set

Comment: @dkozl I updated my code

Comment: @MarcinZdunek updated

Comment: It is really strange, but the solution was to delete this: Height="{Binding ElementName=ComponentChildsListBox, Path=ActualHeight}". Can someone explain this?

Comment: You use Margin="1" for ListBox. This means that if Grid has the same Height as ListBox, ListBox's 2 pixels on bottom will be out of Grid. The same thing would be with right ListBox's side if your ListBox and Grid would have the same Width.